# API accepts an object, passing an object as json, Only taking top layer of the object

Tags: c#, .net, rest, .net-3.5, asp.net-web-api

I have an WebAPI that accepts an Order class. I create the Order class and serialize it which turns it into a string, and I pass it to my web api.  The data is all there, but when I deserialize it on the API side (for testing only, as I was getting a null reference error), most of my objects are returning back as null (all but the top layer of the object)

Order Class:

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Order
    {
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrdereDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
        public IList<Product> ProductList { get; set; }
    }
```

my original Json string that I call the api method is like so

```
{
    "Address" : {
        "AddressLine1" : "line1",
        "AddressLine2" : "",
        "City" : "Test",
        "Province" : "ON",
        "PostalCode" : "90210",
        "Country" : "US",
        "Email" : "test@gmail.com",
        "Phone" : "234567876"
    },
"OrdereDate" : "\/Date(1400198100000)\/",
    "DeliveryDate" : "\/Date(1400753100000)\/",
"ProductList" : [{
            "ProductCode" : "GT",
            "Name" : null,
            "Description" : null,

        }, {
            "ProductCode" : "CI",
            "Name" : null,
            "Description" : null,
        }
    }
```

That is what is getting passed to the API, but if I deserialize the object back into an Order object, the Address and the ProductList are both null.

EDIT:  The other classes are marked as serialize as well

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Product
    {
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
  [Serializable]
    public class Address
    {
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Province { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

My serialization/API call

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                string serialisedData = js.Serialize(order);

                var response = client.UploadString("mysite.com/Order/NewOrder", serialisedData);
```

Comment: Are the `Product` and `Address` classes marked `[Serializable]` as well?

Comment: which json serializer/deserializer are you using (and is it the same one on both sides)?

Comment: Please show the referenced classes so that this question is answerable.

Comment: Okay updated my question, @EkoostikMartin both classes are serializable as well :(

Comment: That is the json being sent to the webapi from your client, but have you looked at the request header? Is it actually sending all of that properly?

Comment: @TravisJ how do I check that?

Comment: @user3192012 - In the browser. Screenshot example: http://i.imgur.com/KWXlpxc.png

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick swag: Remove the [Serializable] attribute from the classes and try again. The Web API works differently from WCF, which the attributes were designed for. That is generally enough to get things working right.

NOTE: If you need to do deeper JSON mappings, the web API is not quite as mature as some other JSON libraries. Fortunately, you can lay other JSON serializers on top and JSON.NET is included, so you can use its methodology (and attributes) to serialize much better than out of the box. That is my direction to head if you need more JSON serialization/deserialization support.

Comment: BTW, Remove the attribute might sound counter intuitive, but realize the reason it was added to the framework and it makes sense.